# Display an image with a div which can wrap the link

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple html/css web page.
What I am trying to do is having an image and a div. Both will be inline display and in div I want to put a link. But when I put a long link title it is not what I expect it to be.
My code is this-
[code](https://jsfiddle.net/gg7ygdLs/)

```
    <div class="heading"> featured posts
    </div>
    <div class="img_src">
        <img style="height:120px;" src="/uploads/1.jpg"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="link_src">
        <a class="inside_link" href="#">Link will go here but if there is a long title then it may create some problems..</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.img_src{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left:-2%;
}
.link_src{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    width: 61%;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.inside_link{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    font-size: 15px;
}




.heading{
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed","HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-color:white;
    margin-left:-2%;
    margin-right:-2%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I searched on google and StackOverflow but I did not get anything useful.
I want it to look like this(DIV wraps full)-

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You csn use `diplay:table-cell` instead of `inline-block` but also I made edit in html by adding div.post that contain the image and title, and remove the inline-style that gave height to the image

```
<div class="post">


  <div class="img_src">
    <img  src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/22/13/32738A6E00000578-3504412-image-a-6_1458654517341.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="link_src">
    <a class="inside_link" href="#">Link will go here but if there is a long title then it may create some problems..</a>
  </div>


</div>
```

and in the css I give `width:20%;` to `.img_src` and `width:80%;` to `.link_src`   (you can change the widths as you like) and remove height and line height from them and the `diplay:table-cell` will handle those height

```
.post{
  font-size:0;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
.img_src{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:20%;
}
.img_src img{
  width:100%;
}
.link_src{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:80%;
}
.inside_link{
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    font-size: 15px;
}




.heading{
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed","HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-color:white;
    margin-left:-2%;
    margin-right:-2%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/gg7ygdLs/17/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: But link title is very close to the image and when I set margin-left , it is setting margin of the first line of the link but I want to set margin for whole title.

Comment: Ok I think that you gave margin to .inside_link so you will need also to gave it display:block https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/gg7ygdLs/33/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by changing the `inline-block` display to `table-cell` and then apply the `vertical-align:middle;` property on the text container.

That way, the text will be perfectly vertically centered if there are one, two, three lines of content.

```
.parent{
  display: table;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}   
.img_src{
  display: table-cell;
}
.link_src{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: white;
  width: 61%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gg7ygdLs/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are using the wrong approach. Line height is causing you the problem. Your html should look like this

```
<img class="img_src" style="height:120px;" src="/uploads/1.jpg">
        <div class="link_src">
            <div class="inner_link_src">
                <div class="inner_margin">
                    <a href="#">Link will go here but if there is a long title then it may create some problems..</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and your css like this

```
.img_src{
    float:left
}

.link_src{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 61%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: white;
    vertical-align: top;
    display:table;
    height:120px;
}

.inner_link_src{
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
  margin-left:10px;
}

.inner_margin{
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

see the jsfiddle it is working great

https://jsfiddle.net/gg7ygdLs/27/

Comment: Margins must be applied on the inner_margin class

Comment: To avoid any further trouble add wrap all the above html in a div and add overflow:auto to the wrap

Comment: Why margins should be applied on the inner_margin class?.

Comment: because if you add them in the a tag then it applies only to the first line of text. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You just change your **CSS** and **HTML** by following and then you get the desired result.

**CSS:**

```
 .img_src{

    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left:-2%;
}
.link_src{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 0px 3px rgba(204,204,204,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 0px 0px 3px rgba(204,204,204,1);
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 0px 3px rgba(204,204,204,1);
}
.inside_link{
    margin: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 8px;
}




.heading{
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed","HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-color:white;
    margin-left:-2%;
    margin-right:-2%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-style: oblique;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="heading"> featured posts
    </div>

    <div class="link_src">
   <img style="height:120px;" src="http://smashinghub.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Text-Shadow-Box.jpg" />
    <a class="inside_link" href="#">Link will go here but if there is a long title then it may create some problems..</a>
    </div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Harpreet_devgun/gg7ygdLs/32/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code a lot by using Flexbox.

You can use it for your header as well, to center the title.

```
.your-header {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Then the image container. Use  it's more semantic and it's a block element, perfect to wrap an image with a caption or a link in your case:

```
<figure class="your-figure">
  <img class="your-image" src="http://pipsum.com/200x150.jpg"></img>
  <a class="your-link" href="#">Link will go here but if there is a long title then it may create some problems..</a>
</figure>
```

and the CSS

```
.your-figure {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.your-image {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wisd81/grzemq0g/) for the complete code ;)

Follow this if you don't know Flexbox, might seems daunting at first, but when it clicks in your head it will change your life :) [Complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks. I read some tutorials about flex and it looked very useful. Now I am studying from the link you provided :)

Comment: Feel free to ask you need help